# Get current working shift from array with Moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Original question

#### Get nearest time in the past with Moment.js

*Unfortunately the original question wasn't good enough for my use case. However, [M. Mennan Kara's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49084165/4530969) is answering exactly to my original question. So you should find it out.*

***Improved question with the case example can be found below.***

Time is now 04:00 (using 24-hour clock). I'd like to parse string `22:00:00` to Moment.js object.

```js
let parsed = moment('22:00:00', 'HH:mm:ss');
```

That worked like a charm. Unlikely the function returns current day by default. So, my question is: *isn't it possible to parse to the nearest time in the past?*

---

Improved question

#### Get current working shift from array with Moment.js

Following is an example case about how it should work in my project. I have working shifts in array and want to save current shift in `currentShift` variable.

```js
let currentShift = null;

let shifts = [
  { name: 'early', start: '06:00:00', end: '14:00:00' },
  { name: 'late',  start: '14:00:00', end: '22:00:00' },
  { name: 'night', start: '22:00:00', end: '06:00:00' }
];

shifts.forEach(item => {
  let start = moment(item.start, 'HH:mm:ss');
  if (moment(item.start, 'HH:mm:ss') <= moment()) {
    currentShift = item;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

How about if you compare the parsed time with current time and remove one day if it's after current time since you are looking for the nearest time in the past.

```
let parsed = moment('22:00:00', 'HH:mm:ss');
if (parsed.isAfter(moment())) {
    parsed.subtract(1, 'days');
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y40gvsmo/7/

Comment: Sorry, my question was not good enough. This solution is good answer to the original question, but unfortunately it does not work in my case (getting current working shift). I added an example about my use case.